# SwipeRefreshLayout behind ActionBar

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

When using a SwipeRefreshLayout in combination with a overlay mode ActionBar, the loading animation will be displayed behind the actionbar, making it almost invisible.

Is there anything I can do to show it on top of the actionbar?

Comment: I have the same issue, can't figure out a way to show the loader in the right position

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the Material Design version of the appcompat-v7 library (v21.0.0), `SwipeRefreshLayout` gets a method to set the Progress View offset.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setProgressViewOffset(boolean,%20int,%20int)

> public void **setProgressViewOffset** (boolean scale, int start, int end)
>
> The refresh indicator starting and resting position is always positioned near the top of the refreshing content. This position is a consistent location, but can be adjusted in either direction based on whether or not there is a toolbar or actionbar present.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *scale*   Set to true if there is no view at a higher z-order than where the progress spinner is set to appear.
>
> *start*   The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should appear.
>
> *end*     The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should come to rest after a successful swipe gesture.

Comment: I have imported the new library and it's working fine (I can see the new swiperefreshanimation) but I need to move it down. Using this method I get `The method setProgressViewOffset(boolean, int, int) is undefined for the type SwipeRefreshLayout`. Please see my question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713832/setprogressviewoffsetboolean-int-int-is-undefined-for-the-type-swiperefreshl

Answer (score 20):

Try this code:

```
int top_to_padding=100;
swipe_refresh_layout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0,top_to_padding);
```

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 4):

the answer of Vijay Rajput works for me, but the problem was only on Kitkat or hight so I included:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    swipeLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0,100);
}`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting paddingTop on the SwipeRefreshLayout, setting the layout_marginTop will make the progress bar visible:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
```

Comment: Yes, but the list must be able to scroll under the action bar to make the animation look good (I use an overlay mode Actionbar; the action bar is semi-transparent). The list must be the direct child of SwipeFreshLayout, so this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This was the best solution before the v21 of the appcompat-v7 library. If you're using v21 or newer, please check the approved answer. In case you're using appcompat-v7 < 21 API this would still help you.

---

You can fix this easily by copying the SwipeRefreshLayout (and its dependencies) into your project and change where the progress bar is displayed, adding a top margin.

To make it easy for everyone I released a library with the margin implemented. Take a look at this: https://github.com/Naroh091/SwipeRefreshLayoutOverlay

Hope it helps!

Comment: Too bad this solution involves copying the whole code of the SwipeRefreshLayout class.

Comment: We need someone who works on this at Google create a method for it. Hate having to move away from official code.

Comment: link is not valid anymore.

Comment: @NicolasTyler thank you for the warning, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have currently come across this when I upgraded my dependency from appcompat 19.1.0 to 21.0.0 and made no code changes.

This is actually a known issue with SwipeRefreshLayout in appcompat 21.0.0.

Look here for a workaround:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712