# SwipeRefreshLayout with Actionbar overlay, animation is behind actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overlay, android-animation, swiperefreshlayout

I have a SwipeRefreshLayout which has a ListView inside. I have also ActionBar overlay set and basically the top of the ListView is behind the action bar along with the SwipeRefreshLayout and when i trigger the refresh the animation is behind the ActionBar ergo not visible. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413680/swiperefreshlayout-behind-actionbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Material Design version of the appcompat-v7 library (v21.0.0), `SwipeRefreshLayout` gets a method to set the Progress View offset.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setProgressViewOffset(boolean,%20int,%20int)

> public void **setProgressViewOffset** (boolean scale, int start, int end)
>
> The refresh indicator starting and resting position is always positioned near the top of the refreshing content. This position is a consistent location, but can be adjusted in either direction based on whether or not there is a toolbar or actionbar present.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *scale*   Set to true if there is no view at a higher z-order than where the progress spinner is set to appear.
>
> *start*   The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should appear.
>
> *end*     The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should come to rest after a successful swipe gesture.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting paddingTop on the SwipeRefreshLayout, setting the layout_marginTop will make the progress bar visible:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have currently come across this when I upgraded my dependency from appcompat 19.1.0 to 21.0.0 and made no code changes.

This is actually a known issue with SwipeRefreshLayout in appcompat 21.0.0.

Look here for a workaround: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712