# GridView under Toolbar - Hide ToolBar when Scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, toolbar, material-design

I have the following layout for my Activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</FrameLayout>
```

content_fragment is the place where I replace a fragment which includes a gridView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.test.android.client.fragment.BurgerGridFragment">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_extra_small"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/margin_extra_small" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

My idea is as soon I scroll in GridView, Toolbar should appears/disappears with animation:

```
if (shown) {


view.animate()
                    .translationY(0)
                    .alpha(1)
                    .setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        } else {
            view.animate()
                    .translationY(-view.getBottom())
                    .alpha(0)
                    .setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }
```

The problem is first grid items have partially overlapped by toolBar.
Do you know how to solve the problem?

Addenda:

I have tried RelativeLayout as well as LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout for my Activity, but that will not be a solution and I get into another problem as described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163698/hiding-toolbar-when-scrolling-layout-under-toolbar-does-not-disapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an empty header to your `GridView` that would stay hidden under your custom header to provide the desired spacing. Since standart `GridView` does not support headers, you would need to use [`HeaderGridView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java). I have used this widget several times and it always works well.

Since you are using `SwipeRefreshLayout` you will also need need to adjust its progress view position. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26494724/4584675) this can be done with [`setProgressViewOffset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setProgressViewOffset).

Comment: Then it ends up to a similar problem like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184409/add-swiperefreshlayout-to-recyclerview-when-it-has-a-empty-header, So it is not a real solution.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that.. Would you like to have the refresh stripes above or below the toolbar?

Comment: Ofcourse bellow, at the top of grid/list, but not first item as it is header.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: I will give it a try soon, +1 for your help.

Comment: setProgressViewOffset() get two parameters : start and end. Do you know how to get the default ones?

Comment: How do you set the height of toolbar? _End_ should be the same I guess. Don't know about the default _start_, I would try some constants and see how they work.. At [some places](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712) they even use 0.

Answer (score 2):

try to change FrameLayout to LinearLayout with orientation vertical.
Then the Gridview will placed bellow the Toolbar.